# Select only the most recent records by record ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access database, in it, I have a number of records where I need to pull just the latest information .

Here's the code  I am trying to get working :

```
SELECT c.RecordID, c.Employee, c.DecShotDate, c.DecShotLocation, c.DecReason, c.DecExplanation, e.ID, e.Employee, c.Training, c.CompletedDate, IIf([DecShotLocation]=0,"Hospital", IIf([DecShotLocation]=1,"MCS", IIf([DecShotLocation]=2,"Other Employer",IIf([DecShotLocation]=3,"Pharmacy",IIf([DecShotLocation]=4,"Primary Care",IIf([DecShotLocation]=5,"Urgent Care"," ")))))) AS StrDecLoc
FROM ((EmployeeInformation AS e 
INNER JOIN CompletedTrainings AS c ON e.ID = c.Employee
) AS t
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT MAX(RecordID) AS mID, c.Training 
FROM CompletedTrainings c
)
ON t.RecordID = c.RecordID
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT c.Training, c.RecordID AS dID
FROM CompletedTrainings c
) AS d
ON c.RecordID = d.dID
GROUP BY c.Training
) as M
on M.RecordID = t.RecordID
WHERE c.Training = 69 AND (((c.CompletedDate+365)>=IIf(Forms![frm_Decflu]!FrameAllOrCurrent=1,(c.CompletedDate+365),Date())))
GROUP BY c.RecordID, c.Employee, c.DecShotDate, c.DecShotLocation, c.DecReason, c.DecExplanation, e.ID, e.Employee, c.Training, c.CompletedDate);
```

The idea here, is I need 1 Training, and I need just the employees who took that training, and only the last time they took it.

Currently I am getting a Syntax error in the JOIN statement.

So the two inner Selects:

```
(
SELECT MAX(RecordID) AS mID, c.Training 
FROM CompletedTrainings c
)
ON t.RecordID = c.RecordID
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT c.Training, c.RecordID AS dID
FROM CompletedTrainings c
) AS d
ON c.RecordID = d.dID
GROUP BY c.Training
) as M
on M.RecordID = t.RecordID
```

Work together to get me a list of the last time every training was taken.
And the first select

```
SELECT c.RecordID, c.Employee, c.DecShotDate, c.DecShotLocation, c.DecReason, c.DecExplanation, e.ID, e.Employee, c.Training, c.CompletedDate, IIf([DecShotLocation]=0,"Hospital", IIf([DecShotLocation]=1,"MCS", IIf([DecShotLocation]=2,"Other Employer",IIf([DecShotLocation]=3,"Pharmacy",IIf([DecShotLocation]=4,"Primary Care",IIf([DecShotLocation]=5,"Urgent Care"," ")))))) AS StrDecLoc
FROM ((EmployeeInformation AS e 
INNER JOIN CompletedTrainings AS c ON e.ID = c.Employee
```

Pulls just the information I need from each of the tables.

Independently these work, except that the first select pulls duplicate trainings (These trainings are done yearly).

I am trying to get rid of that duplication, to produce a yearly report on who has had a specific training.

Sample Tables :

tbl_E

| IDNum | LastName | GivenName | Active | PersonalInfoColumns | EmployeeName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dole | Bob | -1 | stuff | Bob Dole |
| 2 | Clinton | Bill | -1 | stuff | Bill Clinton |
| 3 | Bush | George HW | 0 | stuff | George HW Bush |
| 4 | Reagan | Ronald | 0 | stuff | Ronald Reagan |
| 5 | Eastwood | Clint | -1 | stuff | Clint Eastwood |

tbl_C

| RecordID | Employee | Training | CompletedDate | DSD | DSL | DR | DE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 69 | mmddyyyy | 0 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 74 | mmddyyyy |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 3 | 69 | mmddyyyy | 1 | somewhere | 4 | somereason |
| 4 | 4 | 52 | mmddyyyy |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 1 | 74 | mmddyyyy |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | 2 | 69 | mmddyyyy | 2 | somewhere | 4 | somereason |
| 7 | 5 | 69 | mmddyyyy | 0 |  |  |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 972 | 1 | 69 | mmddyyyy | 1 | somewhere | 4 | somereason |
| 973 | 5 | 69 | mmddyyyy | 1 | somewhere | 2 | somereason |
| 974 | 1 | 73 | mmddyyyy | 1 | somewhere | 2 | somereason |
| 974 | 2 | 69 | mmddyyyy | 0 |  |  |  |

tbl_T (not relevant but it is linked to tbl_C)

| ID | TrainingName | requalifiy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 69 | Shots | yearly |
| 73 | Reference | Once |
| 74 | CORI | Once |
| 52 | Training | yearly |

The ideal output of this query is this :

| RecordID | Employee | Training | CompletedDate | DSD | DSL | DR | DE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 69 | mmddyyyy | 1 | somewhere | 4 | somereason |
| 972 | 1 | 69 | mmddyyyy | 1 | somewhere | 4 | somereason |
| 973 | 5 | 69 | mmddyyyy | 1 | somewhere | 2 | somereason |
| 974 | 2 | 69 | mmddyyyy | 0 |  |  |  |

Assuming employee 3 didn't do it after the first time.

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: ...and what is the error message? (append it to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access is a little bizarre in using SQL as standard, so this SQL that would perfectly work in any SQL backend might not in access. Unfortunately at this moment I don't have a chance to try:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tbl_C t1 
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Max(recordId) AS maxRecId 
   FROM tbl_C WHERE Training=69 GROUP BY Employee) t2
ON t1.RecordId = t2.maxRecId;
```

(If you want, you can join to other such as tbl_E to get names)